# INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink: Writer callback called

Tags: hadoop, docker, flume

I googled this error. I don't get any solutions.

I am having pseudo distributed hadoop-flume. It's dockerized application. I am trying to write in the console from flume. It works. I am trying to write in hdfs. it says writer callback failed.

flume.conf

```
  a2.sources = r1
  a2.sinks = k1
  a2.channels = c1

 a2.sources.r1.type = netcat
 a2.sources.r1.bind = localhost
 a2.sources.r1.port = 5140

 a2.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
 a2.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
 a2.sinks.k1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
 a2.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:8020/user/root/syslog/%y-%m-%d/%H%M/%S
 a2.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = events
 a2.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundUnit = minute
 a2.sinks.k1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true

 # Use a channel which buffers events in memory
 a2.channels.c1.type = memory
 a2.channels.c1.capacity = 10000
 a2.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

 # Bind the source and sink to the channel
 a2.sources.r1.channels = c1
 a2.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

flume run command

```
 /usr/bin/flume-ng agent --conf-file /etc/flume-ng/conf/flume.conf --name a1 -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

All hadoop services are running. How to solve this error? Any Idea?

Comment: can you post the error log also.

Comment: where can i get logs?

Comment: where did you see INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink: Writer callback called?

Comment: I am writing data into the console. Source is netcat. Sink is console. So i see in the console.

Comment: I am wondering if you solved this problem?